# Cancel button click from UI hit method immediately while another method execution still in progress in MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, angular5

I am using Angular5 in frontend and MVC in backend in my application.I have 2 buttons "Run" and "Cancel". While click on Run button, MVC method(GetGridResult) is called which then make SQL connection and display the result into the grid in UI .Sometime, result is too large so i want to cancel the query in between as user will not wait longer time.
but problem is while click on cancel button , Cancel method (CancelGridResult) is called in MVC only after GetGridResult complete its execution(getting result from SQL server).
I want both methods should not depend on each other i.e. as soon as i click on cancel button from UI "CancelGridResult" method hit but now CancelGridResult hit only after GetGridResult execution complete(currently both methods running sequentially).
Kindly let me know how do i hit "CancelGridResult" while another method "GetGridResult" still in progress on clicking cancel button.

I made GetGridResult asynchronous by adding async and await but still both method run sequentially.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'd recommend taking [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and then reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as an introduction to how SO works, and how to effectively ask a question.